# No data returned when I incorporate dataTable in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am new to datatables. I am trying to incorporate datatable into an existing ASP.NET MVC application. Below is my `Index.cshtml` page. I tried to incorporate datatable in this code:

```
<table id="BookAssignmentTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered"   style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Book</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Group</th>
       
        <th>Updated By</th>
        <th>Updated On</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

</table>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts{

    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var Popup, dataTable;
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
          
            dataTable =  $("#BookAssignmentTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/BookAssign/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Book" },
                    { "data": "Office" },
                    { "data": "Group" },
                   
                    { "data": "UpdatedBy" },
                    { "data": "UpdatedOn" },
                    {
                        "data": "ID", "render": function (data) {

                            return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("StoreOrEdit", "bookAssignment_new")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>Edit</a> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete(" + data + ")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>Delete</a>";
                        },

                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable": false,
                        "width" : "150px"
                    }
                ],

                "language": {
                    "emptyTable" : "No data found please click on <b>Add New </b> Button"
                }
            });
        });

        function PopupForm(url) {

            var formDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url)
                .done(function (response) {

                    formDiv.html(response);

                    Popup = formDiv.dialog({

                        autoOpen : true,
                        resizable : false,
                        title : 'Fill Book Assignment Details',
                        height : 500,
                        width : 700,
                        close: function () {

                            Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
        </script>
```

Below is my `BookAssignController`:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
        using (ACREmployeeEntities db= new ACREmployeeEntities())
        {
            List<bookAssignment_new> bookList = db.bookAssignment_new.ToList<bookAssignment_new>();
            return Json(new { data = bookList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

This is in my `route.config` file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "BookAssign", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
}
```

When I run my code, I see this URL, but I don't see any to data.

```
https://localhost:44374/BookAssign/Index
```

When I changed the url to

```
https://localhost:44374/BookAssign/getdata
```

the debugger stops at the `getData` method in the controller and returns the correct data. I am not sure what am I don't wrong and why I don't see any data.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time appearance of .cshtml, you could do the following process:

First you should add `<tbody></tbody>` behind your `<thead></thead>` section.

In `<tbody></tbody>` section, you add a loop like this:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < yourData.ItsLength; i++)
{
     <tr>
        <td>yourData[i].YourFirstAttribute</td>
        <td>yourData[i].YourSecondAttribute</td>
        <td>yourData[i].YourThirdAttribute</td>
     </tr>
}
```

P/S: I recommend you put your js script separately outside .cshtml file.